# Getting 404 Page Not Found error when deploying a static website with included files and build configurations on NETLIFY

Tags: html, netlify

Currently facing an issue while attempting to deploy a static website, as I continuously encounter a "404 Page Not Found" error. Despite ensuring that all my files and build configurations are included, I am still unable to resolve this problem.

I am trying to deploy a simple portfolio website built with HTML, CSS and JS on Netlify but getting a page not found error after deployment. I have placed everything below:

[image]

[image]